# Fortran -Solve math equation in fortran

Tags: math, fortran

So i have hw make a fortran script solve a math equation so i make this

```
Program Tugas

implicit none
Real :: a,b,c,d,e,f,h,s,x
integer :: i,j

!menentukan parameter a,b,dan c
a = 3
b =4
c = 10000

!menentukan dikriminan

d = (b**2 – 4*a*c)

if (d > 0.0000000010)then
e = ( -b + sqrt(d))/2*a
f = ( -b + sqrt(d))/2*a
write(*,*),”nilai x1=” , e,”       dan     nilai x2=”,f

else if ( d == 0 ) then
e = ( -b + sqrt(d))/2*a
f = ( -b + sqrt(d))/2*a
write(*,*),”nilai x1=” , e,”       dan     nilai x2=”,f
ELSE
d = -d
x = (-b)/2*a
f =  sqrt(d)/2*a
write(*,*),”nilai x1 imajinear =”, x ,” + “, f,”i”
write(*,*),”nilai x1 imajinear =”, x ,” – “, f,”i”
end if

End Program Tugas
```

but in the end error and its says

```
Error: Invalid character 0xE2 at (1)
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',22)">main.f95:22:9</span>:
   22 | d = (b**2 – 4*a*c)
      |         1
```

im newbie in fortran and i dont know what error it was, please help me :'

Comment: Try typing that line in again. Perhaps an invisible character got pasted in by mistake.

Comment: Cutting and pasting that into a file and compiling suggests the - is some weird sideways dash ant no a minus sign - did you copy and paste this from somewhere?  Changing it to a minus sign fixes that, but you have more problems in your code in the `write(*, *),`  lines - delete that comma, it shouldn't be there